# проблема в Django форме

Tags: html, python, django, form

Учу Django, и осваиваю встроиные Django формы. проблема в том что у меня есть форма, которая должна либо создавать тег либо выводить ошибку(думаю это проблема с указанием url в шаблоне, но я проверял всё равно не работает, кнопка просто ничего не возвращает)

шаблон tag_create.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Tag Create - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="{% url 'tag_create_url' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

       {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ field.errors }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.label }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>

       {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Tag</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

# some-article

urlpatterns = [
    path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
    path('tags/', tag_list, name='tag_list_url'),
    path('tag/create', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),
    path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url'),
]
```

файл с самой формой forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import Tag
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class TagForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = forms.SlugField(max_length=50)

    title.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    slug.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()

        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug must not be created')
        else:
            return new_slug

    def save(self):
        new_tag = Tag.objects.create(title=self.cleaned_data['title'],
                                     slug=self.cleaned_data['slug']
                                     )
        return new_tag
```

и вьюха которая реализовывает методы get и post:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View

from blog.models import Post, Tag
from blog.forms import TagForm
from .utils import ObjectDetailMixin

class TagCreate(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = TagForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = TagForm(request.POST)

        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_tag = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_tag)
        return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': bound_form})
```

Comment: У вас 1) Создается объект **Tag**? 2) У вас определен в модели **Tag** метод **get_absolute_url** ?

Comment: Да всё это дела описано:                                                                                                       
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Comment: В метод `post` заходит вообще?

Comment: Как это проверить?